# How to expose Kettle transformation as a service?

Tags: data-mining, etl, pentaho, kettle

What would it take to expose a Kettle transformation as a (web) service?
REST, SOAP, anything will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need carte:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+User+Documentation

Or perhaps just use the BI Server - very easy to setup webservices in there, and being overhauled/made even easier in the next major release.

The enteprise edition has something called a DI server.  Which presumably does this.  But then you'd know that if you were an EE customer!

Answer (score 1):

An old post, but thought I would point to [this nice article](http://www.ibridge.be/?p=199) which may help people trying to do this.